# Rewrite git author history for signed commits

Tags: git, git-rebase, revision-history

I know I can change the author/committer history in git via the provided github script: https://help.github.com/articles/changing-author-info/

This unfortunately does not work, if you have signed commits/merges. It will sort of work, but all commit messages are spammed with the gpg signature itself in a multiline comment and not signed.

Is there any way I can rewrite the author history and also sign them again without having the gpg string inside the commit message?

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite author/committer history of a [git repository](https://github.com/davidfokkema/git-rewrite-author). This is a useful tool to rewrite author/commit history.

Comment: And it removes the now invalid spammy signature comments?

Comment: @Thilo probably a record of it maybe maintained, incase you wish to revert back to the old comments

Comment: This does not work. It will use the gpg-signature and prepend it to the commit message. It does the same as the above mentioned method from github.